# How can we detemine Infimum and Supremum over $x_n$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, supremum-and-infimum

If x ∈ R, we write q = [x], the integer part of x such that x−1 < q ≤ x.

Thus [x] ≤ x. Define $x_n = n^2/(2n+1) -[n/2]$,where [n/2] is the integer part of n/2.

I should calculate **inf $x_n$ and sup $x_n$**.

I traced the sequence [1/3,-1/5,2/7,-2/9,3/11...]

The supremum $x_n$ is 1/3, but what about the infimum?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Note that $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ is $n/2$ when $n$ is even and $(n-1)/2$ when $n$ is odd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When $n$ is odd,  $\lfloor n/2\rfloor=(n-1)/2$ , so $x_n=\dfrac{n^2}{2n+1}-\dfrac{n-1}2=\dfrac{n+1}{4n+2}>0$.

when $n$ is even, $\lfloor n/2\rfloor=n/2$, so $x_n=\dfrac{n^2}{2n+1}-\dfrac n2=-\dfrac n{4n+2}$.

Can you now show $\inf x_n=-\dfrac14$?

Comment: yes! Thanks for the information! That means i calculated my supremum wrong ? I just substituted with the formula based on the given and noticed that the least upper one would be 1/3.

Comment: you're welcome, and you were correct that the supremum is $1/3$

Comment: alright, but doesn't the limit as n approaches infinity for xn odd gives 1/4? which should be lim sup?

Comment: It's $\color{red}-1/4$